# Proving Integral Test?

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals, riemann-sum

Assume that $f(x) \geq 0$ and that $f$ decreases monotonically on $[1, \infty]$.
Prove $\int_{1}^{\infty} f(x)dx$ converges iff $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n)$ converges.

### My proof:

If $f$ is non-negative and monotonically decreasing, it is integrable on any finite interval.
Consider a partition of $[1,t]$ consisting of the $t$ points $1,2,...,t$. 
Since the upper Riemann sum for the partition is $\sum_{n=1}^{t-1} f(n)$ and the lower Riemann sum is $\sum_{n=2}^{t} f(n)$, it clearly follows that
$$\sum_{n=2}^{t} f(n) \leq \int_{1}^{t} f(x)dx \leq \sum_{n=1}^{t-1} f(n).$$
Hence we have that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n) -f(1) \leq \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \int_{1}^{t} f(x)dx \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n).$$
It follows that the seqeuence of partial sums of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n)$ is bounded if and only if $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \int_{1}^{t} f(x)dx$ is bounded, hence the limits either both exist or both are infinite.
Thus the result follows.

Something feels off... would the above proof be sufficiently rigorous?

Comment: You should add a few things. First since $f(x)>0$, the integral and partial sums are growing as $t$ goes to $\infty$, which says that both share the divergence to $\infty$ if this is the case. Then each are monotone increasing and bounded by the other in the case of convergence, hence the iff...

Answer (score 1):

Apart from one missing detail - the integrability of $f$ - this looks fine to me. You can deduce integrability fairly easily, and may already have established that result. As pointed out in the comments, you could expand on the "converge or diverge together" comment as well.

Answer (score 0):

First review what a Riemann sum is and what the definition of an improper integral is. Your sums are not Riemann sums. Then, choose an arbitrary partition $P$ of your interval $[0,t]$, find a relationship between the upper sums $U(P)$, the lower sums $L(P)$ and $f$ and apply the squeeze theorem or use an $\epsilon - \delta $ argument by estimating the difference $U(P)-L(P)$. Finally, take the limit as $t\rightarrow \infty $.

Comment: I don't understand, how are they not Riemann sums?

Comment: Sorry I meant to say that you have used a particular partition, but the Riemann integral is defined as a certain limit vaild for an arbitrary partition $P$ so if you want to do this rigorously, you need to follow the steps I outlined. There are two limits you need to consider here: the one defining the integral on your interval $[0,t]$ and the one you take at the end when you let $t$ get arbitrarily large. If and when you study nets, all this will be a lot easier.